# Clicking the button does not work - React

Tags: reactjs, function, setstate

I use a component called "Modal" that I want to make global so I can use it in any other component. Modal will be used in all the components that need it. 
My problem is that now the onclick {this.props.stateModal} in Widgets does not work and show nothing.

This is my Widgets.js

```
class Widgets extends Component {    
    render(){
        return (
            <aside className="widgets">
                <div id="bq-datos">
                    <span>Todas tus campañas</span>
                    <a onClick={this.props.stateModal} className="content-datos orange" data-bq-datos="999"><div>Llamadas <span>ENTRANTES</span></div></a>
                    <a className="content-datos violet" data-bq-datos="854"><div>Llamadas <span>SALIENTES</span></div></a>
                </div>
                {
                this.props.isModalOpen
                    ? (

                <Modal                    
                    stateModal = {this.props.stateModal}
                    isModalOpen={this.props.isModalOpen}  >
                    <ModalWidgets/>
                </Modal>
                    )
                    : null
                }
                <Comunicacion/>
            </aside>
        );
    }
}
```

I need {this.props.stateModal} to work on my Modal component (in Modal.js)

This is my Modal.js with code for {this.props.stateModal} but not works.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Modal extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            isModalOpen: false,
        };
        this.stateModal = this.stateModal.bind(this);
    }

    stateModal() {
        this.setState({
            isModalOpen: !this.state.isModalOpen
        });
        alert('¡Ohhhh');
    }

    render(){
        if(this.props.isOpen){
            return (

                <div id="modal">
                    {this.props.children}
                    <ModalWidgets/>
                </div>
            );
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
}

class ModalWidgets extends Component {
    render(){
        if(this.props.isModalOpen){
            return(
                <article id="md-descansos" className="medium">
                hola tú!!
            </article>
            );
        }
        else{
            return(
                <div>k pasa!</div>
            );
        }
    }
}

export default Modal;
```

I think that i need do something in my Modal.js but i don't know what it is

**Edit:** 
I have changed the components to use Modal as the parent of all the other Modal that I want to use, such as ModalWidgets. But now when you click on the button of {this.props.stateModal} in Widgts not works.

Thanks!

Comment: where do you use `BkUser`?

Comment: I use BkUser in my Header.js file in the Header class. In the return I make a conditional by the state of the user

Comment: do you have the code on codeshare? or add it here.

Comment: My code BKUser It's right here, in my first code block. You have to scroll to see it

Comment: I want to see how you use it. `<BKUser ... />`

Comment: https://codeshare.io/5eopLA this is my full code

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `stateModal` function somewhere in your `Modal` component. Something like:

```
    render(){
        if(this.props.isOpen){
            return (

            <ModalGenerico>
                <div id="modal">
                  <button type="button" onClick={this.stateModal}>Click here</button>
                  {this.props.children}
                </div>
            </ModalGenerico>
            );
        } else {
            return <ModalGenerico />;
        }
    }
```

The `button` in the example above should be replaced with your `backdrop` of the modal (or anything else as you like).

Edited: You should take a look at this article [State vs Props](https://lucybain.com/blog/2016/react-state-vs-pros/). Because I notice that you weren't clear the usage of them.
Besides, I don't think there's such thing called `global component` as you described. Every components in react are reusable and can be imported anywhere in the project.

Comment: Thanks @Pho Huynh but it's not my problem. I edit my original text for add explanations.